# How do I disabled client-side logging in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So I know you can use the code below, to set server-side logging to a minimum.

```
io.set('log level', 0);
```

However I still get a lot of handshake messaging on the client, and wondered if anyone knows how to disable it, I checked the documentation and couldn't find a setting for it.

Most of the messages I get look like this:

```
XHR finished loading: "http://...".
```

Comment: That's the browser logging, not socket.io I believe.

Comment: Yeh I think you might be right ><

Answer (score 1):

If you use firebug console change it option
unckeck `show XMLHttpRequest`
http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/08/01/How-to-debug-XmlHttpRequest-with-Firebug.aspx